# Getting notification when value source of a dependency property changes

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

Is there a way to get a notification when the value source of a dependency property changes?

I have created an attached property for setting labels that inherit the value to child elements:

```
LabelProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached ("Label", typeof (string), typeof (Class1), 
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata (null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits, OnLabelChanged));
```

I than set the a value to the Label property on a parent element, effectively applying it to all child elements. At some point a child element sets the same value as the local value for the attached property (in XAML). Although the value doesn't actually changes, the value source changes from *Inherits* to *Local*.

Is there a way to capture such changes in the value source?

Comment: The *Class1* in the property creation refers to the owner of the property, not to which object it can be assigned. The SetXXX and GetXXX static method accept DependencyObject as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

There is not such a thing like callback when precedence changes.

However you can always ask for the current priority by using DependencyPropertyHelper class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencypropertyhelper.getvaluesource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.valuesource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Btw if the value is being set through the local property setter you could attached your custom logic there signaling you SetValue was called locally. I hope this helps you.

**EDIT:**

To track down any value setting you could subscribe to coercion.

```
    public static int GetMyProperty(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (int)obj.GetValue(MyPropertyProperty);
    }

    public static void SetMyProperty(DependencyObject obj, int value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MyProperty", typeof(int), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(0, null, delegate(DependencyObject o, object value) { /*do something here*/ return value; }));
```

Comment: I know about DependencyPropertyHelper.GetValueSource but it doesn't help me much because I don't have any place to call it.  The value of the child property is set in XAML, so I cannot use the attached property's SetXXX static method do check the value source.

Comment: Yes you can use SetXXX. Setting value in XAML is exactly passing SetXXX method.

Comment: Setting value of attached property in XAML doesn't use the SetXXX method (also mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568860/why-attached-property-set-and-get-static-methods-are-not-called-in-xaml))

Comment: I am sorry I thought all the time we are talking about members. Here is code for you. Take a look at the edits in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thanks to dev hedgehog for the help.

After digging into this issue for few days new, I don't believe that there is solution for this situation. I was unable to find a way to cause WPF to raise a property change event when the source of the value changes from *Inherits* to *Local* (if someone find a way to do it, I'll be happy know).

The direction of using the Coerce mechanism looked promising at first, so I tried to do something like this:

```
private static object CoeracLabel (DependencyObject d, object value)
{
    LabelProperty.DefaultMetadata.PropertyChangedCallback (d, new DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs (LabelProperty, value, value));
    return value;
}
```

But after fiddling with that approach for half an hour I had to discard it as well, because when the coerce method is called the value source has not been updated yet so I cannot run any logic that depends on it.

Given that, I decided to change the solution and remove the property value inheritance. The dependency property is now created without the *Inherits* flag and in the in property changed callback I try to find a parent element with a different value.

```
string parentLabel = GetParentLabel (d);
.
.

private static string GetParentLabel (DependencyObject child)
    {
        string parentLabel = null;

        child = LayoutHelper.GetParent (child, false);

        LayoutHelper.FindLayoutOrVisualParentObject (child, x =>
        {
            string label = GetLabel (x);
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty (label))
            {
                parentLabel = label;
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }, true);

        return parentLabel;
    }
```